# How Can Use Postgresql Array_Append() And Array_Remove() In Yii?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii

How can use PostgreSQL `array_append()` and `array_remove()` in Yii? I am trying to update array type attribute on following table rows-

```
CREATE  TABLE Books(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
name UUID[])

Sample data rows: 
1       NULL
2       NULL

$books=Books::model()->findByPk($id);
$books->name='array_append(name, $Name_key_array)';
$books->save();
```

I have found following error:

```
CDbException
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

But If I use array directly then its work but not when using variable name i.e.

```
array_append({1,2,3}, {4})
```

Also, I already tried few more ways but haven't found any success. I hope will find some great ideas to fix this issue.

Comment: Check the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the array_append() in other way. it should be like this

```
SELECT array_append(ARRAY[1,2], 3);
 array_append
--------------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

So if i correct yours, it should be

```
$books->name='array_append($Name_key_array, name)';
```

for removing elements from an array, check this solution: http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2013/06/removing-values-from-a-postgresql-array/

to an array in PostgreSQL data must be inserted in the following way,

```
INSERT INTO table (arr_col) VALUES ('{val1,val2, val3}');
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: Its not working. Also, I have tried with CDbExpression but it was displaying following error "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" " My Code: $books->name=new CDbExpression('array_append(name,$Name_key_array)');

Comment: what happens if you hard code the values like this to see if it works. array_append(columname, value). i.e array_append(name, 5)

Comment: If I use array directly then its works but not when using variable name.

Comment: Can you please update the question by stating the attempt you made now to resolve without variable name.